# Android: Is Possible to Passing parameter from CursorAdapter to Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-cursoradapter

I just want to pass a variable that I get from cursor to Service. But always get a `NullPointerException`.

This is my adapter, which I use to show data into listView.

```
public class DetailCategoryCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

private Services services;

public DetailCategoryCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_detail, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dplay);

int titleColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_TITLE);

int urlColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_URL);

    String title = cursor.getString(titleColumnIndex);
    String url = cursor.getString(urlColumnIndex);

    nameTextView.setText(title);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent sIntent = new Intent(context, Services.class);
                sIntent.putExtra("url", url);
                services.startService(sIntent); // in this part always show NullPointerEception
                Log.v("url", url);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Or is there a better way to do it? Need advice. Thanks

Comment: yes, use `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

Comment: he dint init `services` @pskink possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @SantanuSur fair enough - i simply say that `OnClickListener` is not the best thing when dealing with `ListView`s

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your `onBind` it wont throw the exception. (because your `services` is null)

```
Intent sIntent = new Intent(context, Services.class);
            sIntent.putExtra("url", url);
            context.startService(sIntent);
```

Comment: @UgyAstro feel free to update the answer if it worked :)